# Get value from from a json_array in oracle

Tags: arrays, json, oracle, plsql

i need the values of a json_array. I tried this:

```
    DECLARE
   l_stuff        json_array_t;
BEGIN
   l_stuff := json_array_t ('["Stirfry", "Yogurt", "Apple"] ');  

   FOR indx IN 0 .. l_stuff.get_size - 1
   LOOP
        INSERT INTO t_taböe (name, type)
         VALUES(l_stuff.get(i), 'TEXT');
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the position as `i` instead of `indx`; but you need a string so use `get_string(indx)` as @Sayan said.

But if you try to use that directly in an insert you'll get "ORA-40573: Invalid use of PL/SQL JSON object type" because of a still-outstanding (as far as I know) [bug](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2490027_1.html).

To work around that you can assign the string to a variable first:

```
  l_name := l_stuff.get_string(indx);
  INSERT INTO t_taböe (name, type)
  VALUES(l_name, 'TEXT');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=361b120ec30dcdaababbf3be4ed8b4b7)

Comment: The "Invalid use of PL/SQL JSON object type" bug (?) is still there in Oracle 19c. At this point maybe we need to call it a feature..? :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica - I'm still waiting for "the VARCHAR data type is scheduled to be redefined as a separate data type". You have to keep the faith...

Comment: ANSI VARCHAR support will be in Oracle i - my understanding is that migration support will be provided by contractors from SSI (Satanic Software Inc) who will be required to do their work while wearing parkas and heavy mittens. Any day now. Any day...  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need PL/SQL and can do it in a single SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO t_taböe (name, type)
SELECT value,
       'TEXT'
FROM   JSON_TABLE(
         '["Stirfry","Yogurt","Apple"]',
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           value VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$'
         )
       );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d1f9c24462a88c97b80cc87dcf0d6547)*

Answer (score 2):

First convert the JSON array into an ordinary PL/SQL array, then use a bulk insert.

Here is a [reproducible example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65b553320ca3c636d74ad2e5b97ddedb):

```
create table tab (name varchar2 (8), type varchar2 (8))
/
declare
    type namelist is table of varchar2(8) index by pls_integer;
    names namelist;
    arr json_array_t := json_array_t ('["Stirfry", "Yogurt", "Apple"]');
begin
    for idx in 1..arr.get_size loop 
        names(idx) := arr.get_string(idx-1);
    end loop;
    forall idx in indices of names
        insert into tab (name, type) values (names(idx), 'TEXT');
end;
/
```

The query and outcomes:

```
select * from tab
/
NAME     TYPE    
-------- --------
Stirfry  TEXT    
Yogurt   TEXT    
Apple    TEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `get_string`:

```sql
DECLARE
   l_stuff        json_array_t;
BEGIN
   l_stuff := json_array_t ('["Stirfry", "Yogurt", "Apple"] ');  

   FOR indx IN 0 .. l_stuff.get_size - 1
   LOOP
        --INSERT INTO t_taböe (name, type)
        -- VALUES(l_stuff.get_string(indx), 'TEXT');
        dbms_output.put_line(l_stuff.get_string(indx));
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: `get_string` works fine in the PUT_LINE call but fails in the INSERT statement: "Invalid use of PL/SQL JSON object type".